# How to use resource routes in Laravel 5?

Tags: routes, laravel-5

I have delcared my resource in **routes.php**:

```
Route::resource('user', 'UserController');
```

Now I want to use the link to my html-form:

```
<form action="{{ URL::route('user') }}" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" /><br />
    <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="password" /><br />
    <input type="text" name="uuid" placeholder="uuid" /><br /><br />
    <input name="_type" type="hidden" value="login" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

But Laravel is throwing an exception:

```
production.ERROR: exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Route [user] not defined.
```

Answer (score 1):

Your using wrong route name, use the following

```
<form action="{{ URL::route('user.store') }}" method="post">
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use resources, the name of the route depends on the HTTP method. You can check the names by doing:

```
php artisan route:list
```

You have two options. Use the name you get there or just another helper function (which will be easier i think):

```
URL::action('UserController@store')
```